# Best way to have bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $n$ infinite sets of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\times...\times \mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I tried to search for a way to have bijection between $n$ indexed infinite sets of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\times...\times \mathbb N$,  and integers where each set is an arbitrary multiple of $\mathbb N$, but found nothing.

What is the best formula to accomplish the goal?

Comment: It's identical you just consider them modulo $n$ instead of modulo $2$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField You should make that an answer.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I have edited the question so that it hopefully a bit more worthwhile, apologies for bad question...

Comment: @Dole I like this question and I've studied it for the same reasons you are now. It's worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate Cantor's pairing function.  See "Pairing function - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function.

Geometrically, the resulting "tuple function" is utterly trivial: put the numbers in an array and wind your way back and forth starting from the upper left hand corner.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first $n$ primes sorted in the usual order then there is a bijection between elements of $\mathbb{N}^n$ and powers of these primes. So for say, $n=3$ we would have the primes $2,3,5$ and we'd map $(x,y,z) \rightarrow 2^x3^y5^z$ and this is a bijection by construction. Since this is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ we can write them in the usual order which would be something like $2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,...$ for $n=3$. From here the bijection to the naturals is obvious and so the composition of these two functions is also a bijection giving us a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^n$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consume the elements of the $n$ sets in a round-robin way.

You can even handle a countable infinity of sets by increasing the number of sets on each round.